# Flash movie not working in IE

Tags: flash, slideshow

The page at http://rants-group.com/ works fine in Firefox, not IE. Can anyone look at the source and see any problems?

I cannot get this right at all!

I think I have messed with it too much at this point, not sure what to do!

The code to display the movie is like this:

```
  <div id="mainhome">
<table width="700" height="309" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="350" valign="top" background=""><img src="/images/bckgrnd3.jpg" width="350" height="309" /></td>
    <td width="350" align="right" valign="top"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="350" height="309" id="myFlashContent">
        <param name="movie" value="flash/flashslide.swf?src=flash-here.com&imglist_fn=flash/getimglist.txt&img_path=flash/slides&interval=5000&w=350&h=309" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/flashslide.swf?src=flash-here.com&imglist_fn=flash/getimglist.txt&img_path=flash/slides&interval=5000&w=350&h=309" width="350" height="309">
          <!--<![endif]-->
          <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"> <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /> </a>
          <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
      </object>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to embed a flash movie is to use a library like [`swfobject`](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
There are two ways to use it.

- dynamic loading using javascript
- static loading uses only html

They also have a very easy-to-use configurator that generates the html code that works in every browser to embed to movie into your page.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="350" height="309" id="myFlashContent">
                <param name="movie" value="flash/flashslide.swf?src=flash-here.com&imglist_fn=flash/getimglist.txt&img_path=flash/slides&interval=5000&w=350&h=309" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/flashslide.swf?src=flash-here.com&imglist_fn=flash/getimglist.txt&img_path=flash/slides&interval=5000&w=350&h=309" width="350" height="309">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those IE Conditional Comments are broken.

```
<!--[if !IE]>
  The content in here should ACTUALLY be part of the HTML comment.
  Thus the "double-dash" doesn't re-occur until the very last part
  of the closing tag.
<![endif]-->
```

Though it should be noted, that since no other browser supports IE's conditional comments, the "!IE" syntax doesn't really gain you anything.

It is better to wrap the HTML content you WANT to send to IE in a conditional comment.
e.g.

```
<!--[if IE]>
  This <b>HTML</b> will only appear in Internet Explorer.
  of the closing tag.
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Satay method](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay) for cross-browser interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flash 8 and above, try enabling HTML as a publish output in the Publish Settings.

Take a look at the generated .html file. Remember to link in the external javascript file as well.

Another way would be to use [swfobject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/). Which I prefer to Adobe's method.

There is no need for  and such tags.